# Ошибка вызова из статик контента

Tags: java, static

Компилятор говорит при вызове метода getValues()

Non-static method 'getValue()' cannot be referenced from a static context

хотелось бы узнать почему

```
public  class clous {
protected clous() { r();}
public void r(){
    System.out.println(en.getValue());
}}



public enum en{
           monkey,
           bird;
public  int getValue() {
        return 2;
    }}
```

Comment: Нам тоже хотелось бы узнать почему вы решили, что это должно работать

Comment: Возможно хотелось что-то подобное: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35141026/6104996 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `getValue` в енуме `en` *не является* статическим, но вызывается как статический в методе `clous::r`.

Нужно либо объявить его как статический, либо вызывать для конкретного значения енума `en.monkey` или `en.bird`:

```java
public void r() {
    System.out.println(en.monkey.getValue());
}
```